# Slow sql update query on big tables

Tags: mysql

I have writter sql query and is fine on smaller tables but with 100 thousands records the query is just executing but never performs. Here is my query, Can some one make a faster version of the query.

```
UPDATE members_tb mtb
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT subscription_id,
                   mst.member_id,
                   mst.expiry_date
   FROM member_subscription_tb mst
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT member_id,
             max(expiry_date) AS expiry_date
      FROM member_subscription_tb
      GROUP BY member_id
      LIMIT 0,
            1000) t ON mst.expiry_date = t.expiry_date
   AND t.member_id=mst.member_id) mstb ON mtb.member_id = mstb.member_id
SET mtb.subscription_id = mstb.subscription_id
```

Regards,
Hamayun

**-----Edit-----**

I have two tables members and members_subscriptions
members have members and subscriptions has members subscriptions
one to many relationship.
Now in members table subscription_id is null
I want to update it with subscription_id from members_subscriptions where Max(expiry_date) i.e date expiry is grater and members_id is equal to members.members_id

Comment: Include in your question `show create table member_subscription_tb` output?Can you describe in words what you wan this query to do?

Comment: @danblack
OK. I have two tables members and members_subscriptions members have members and subscriptions has members subscriptions one to many relationship. Now in members table subscription_id is null I want to update it with subscription_id from members_subscriptions where Max(expiry_date) i.e date expiry is grater and members_id is equal to members.members_id

Answer (score 0):

Beneficial indexes:

```
members_tb:  INDEX(subscription_id, member_id)
member_subscription_tb:  INDEX(member_id, expiry_date)
```

You have a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`.  This *may* lead to an unexpected set of rows picked.

Time the subquery (`mstb`) to see whether it is the dominant part of the query.  If so, then we should focus on it.